# Synonym for "increase by one" for use in technical publication

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I was wondering if there is a synonym for the word group "increase by one". Example:

> "If the shoe didn't fit, the shoe size was increased by one size."

I think it sounds weird because of the repetition of *"size"*, however, I think I cannot just delete the second *"size"*. So I thought there might be a synonym to give the sentence more variability.

Or does the sentence below sound natural to native speakers?

> "If the shoe didn't fit, the shoe size was increased by one."

**P.S.: The intended use is a technical publication, so please no colloquial terms or phrases.**

P.P.S.: For the offended footlocker headquarter - imagine a series of tubes in your kitchen that come in sizes one, two, three (I hear already plumbers shouting "no, they don't") and the same situation "If the tube was too small to connect with the sink, the tube size was increased by one."

Yup, I got it now, you could say "the next size was chosen" and I will never ask a question here again because obviously this here is native speaker corner and these kind of synonym questions are trivial. 
So long, and thanks for all the fish.

Comment: I think it sounds funny for a different reason. The size of a specific shoe (pair) is fixed and cannot be changed to be bigger or smaller. If one is too small, a different (larger) one (pair) must be tried.

Comment: Is the technical publication about fitting shoes to feet? It's often better to use the actual sentence you want to write as an example rather than try to come up with something analogous. The analogy might not work the way you hope it will.

Comment: Nah, the analogy is not misleading. The objects (difficult to describe and would only cause further confusion in this thread) come in predefined sizes and the best fitting size has to be chosen by educated guesses or trial and error.

Comment: Try to write/speak in a more natural manner. "If the shoe didn't fit, they tried the next bigger size."

Comment: When selling boots, I always advise buyers to "*go up* a size or a half-size".

Comment: @Fattie That you don't like the shoe example, OK. That you change the meaning of the question with your heading modification, not OK. It was never about shoe sizes.

Comment: @Bread It is not about shoes. Fattie made it about shoes.

Comment: @Mr.T - **definitely change the edit back then**.  This is normal and it is what you should do.  Note that your question really made it sound like it was about shoes (not just "an example").  Please change the headline back any time you wish, it is normal to do so if you don't like an edit.  Cheers!

Comment: If you want a "technical" term, your example sentence(s) should reflect that. Please edit to include the *actual* context of your question.

Comment: How someone in a shoe story would say that is: "If the shoe didn't fit, one size bigger was gotten," or, "If the shoe didn't fit, the clerk would go one size bigger."

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**Increment**, according to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/increment):

> the action or process of increasing especially in quantity or value

[In programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators) this is often used to add one, for example in a loop. In your shoe example you are essentially doing the same, you start with some size and increase by one until it fits.

The opposite, if the shoe is too large, is called [decrement](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decrement). You start with some shoe size and try smaller ones until it fits.

Comment: Good one. I think "...incremented by one" is a concise description.

Comment: @Mr.T Note that one is generally the default increment and may not need to be specified.

Comment: @chrylis In context of shoe sizes, I don't believe it is obvious that one (1) is the default increment.  Generally speaking, "increment" means to raise to the next level, and since US shoe sizes increase in discrete units of 1/2, "increment" could mean to increase by 1/2, to the next available size.  But, I agree, it could also mean to increase by 1.  Here, I would recommend specifying the increment amount explicitly, since ambiguity is generally unwelcome in technical publications.

Comment: @Gooseberry in a computer science or programming context [1 is the default](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators) value when speaking of increment and decrement operators. In another (technical) context or if the reader is not thought to be familiar with them, I agree it's best to define them. Doing that once when first introducing the term should be sufficient.

Comment: It's true that in the weird **shoe size context**, it is unlikely you would use "increment".

Comment: @Fattie it's not unheard of. [Wikipedia's page on shoe sizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoe_size) contains this sentence: *"This also results in different increments between shoe sizes, because usually only "full" or "half" sizes are made."* ;)

Comment: If you were at a shoe store and told the clerk "this one doesn't fit, I think I need to **increment**" you would be much more likely to get funny looks than a bigger shoe.

Comment: @1006a it's fine for technical documents. As stated in the question: *The intended use is a technical publication, so please no colloquial terms and phrases.*

Comment: @JJJ then the example should show the intended use. In the given example, this sounds ridiculous.

Comment: @1006a it does, well, only if you read it out loud. ;)

Comment: Yeah, this is the proper term in modern English. For what it's worth, [the ultimate etymon of '**progress**'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gradior#Latin) *also* had the connotation of 'increase by steps' or 'increments'. It doesn't any more, though, except in highly specialized situations like progressive taxation. Even there, most people won't grok that association but just see it as 'bigger/better over time'.

Comment: @lly Or associate it with the progressives/liberals.

Comment: How about ...bumped up by one?

Comment: Though accurate in a pedantically technical sense, I simply can't imagine actual usage where a speaker would say "If the shoe didn't fit, the shoe size was incremented."

Comment: @JustinC.B. Subsense. Obviously conservatives disagree about the value of tradition/stability, but the progressives have that name bc they see their cause as making society better over time.

Comment: @lly Ah, but the conservatives want a flat & low tax structure, while the progressives/liberals like a progressive tax structure.

Comment: That it "often means increase by one" is an accident and not true in any meaningful sense. Often this is cause by indices being increased by one in each step in a loop -- that increment might be anything and seeing non-one increments is not uncommon and is _still_ referred to as an increment.

Answer (score 14):

"Increase by one" is perfectly fine.  No need to depart from normal (and in this case precise) English in technical documents.  You don't need a fancy word.  If you're indeed talking about something abstract, then yes, "increment" might be better but if you don't know that's the right answer it's probably not the right answer.

Comment: Also, as a native speaker, that second example, "If the shoe didn't fit, the shoe size was increased by one," sounds perfectly natural to me (per the OP's concluding question).

Comment: @Fattie "With Euro it's a random sequence of numbers." If you mean the ["Paris point"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_point) - no it is not random. They come with size steps of halves - the larger the number, the larger the shoe. Increasing resp. decreasing, not random.

Comment: @stumbled on this site — +1 particularly for this pithy gem: ‘ ... but if you don’t know that’s the right answer it’s probably not the right answer’.

Answer (score 11):

The sample sentence is an odd usage. A normal reference to an increase in size would be “The shoe did not fit so we tried one size larger.”

If indeed the writer is talking in past tense about the instructions they used to follow, then “If the shoe did not fit then one of the next size up should be tried", or perhaps “If the shoe did not fit then one of the next larger size should be tried.”

Comment: It is just an example sentence. The intended use is technical, not colloquial.

Comment: Indeed, but i thought it an odd enough usage that i suspected it was taken from a special context, and so tried to answer the general issue by  using “one larger” and then also tried for an answer to the presumed specific issue.

Answer (score 7):

> > I was wondering if there is a synonym for the word group "increase by one".

**Yes**. There are several, although most of them like '**progress**' (orig. "to go up by steps") have taken on expanded senses that obscure the exactness you're trying for. '**Increment**' is the closest in current use, but "increasing by one unit on each iteration" is only going to be understood in programming contexts. Otherwise, people are going to take it as the *distance* between successive steps.

> > Example:
> >
> > > "If the shoe didn't fit, the shoe size was increased by one size."

Er, **no**, there's no single word that works there. Even if you used 'progress' or 'increment' there, it's just like 'increase' that you're going to have to specify the increments you're using.

The idiom for this situation is '**go up**' or '**down**':

> "**If the shoe doesn't fit, go** (**up**|**down**) **to the next size**."

although, given the tentativeness of the proposed solution, it'd also be common to use some version of '**try**':

> "**If the shoe doesn't fit, try the next size** (**up**|**down**)."
>
> > I think it sounds weird because of the repetition of "size"[;] however, I think I cannot just delete the second "size".

You can't. **Rephrase to delete the *first* one**, as above.

> > Or does the sentence below sound natural to native speakers?
> >
> > > "If the shoe didn't fit, the shoe size was increased by one."

**No, it doesn't**, but not because the second 'size' disappeared. It's unnatural because you're using the past tense to propose tentative solutions—not to report the final answer—but talking about those tentative solutions as though they were final. A one-size adjustment might've still been too (small|large).

> **If the shoe didn't fit, we adjusted it up or down one size at a time**.

with the implication "...until it fit". It's still odd that you're speaking in the past tense in a technical publication where you're presumably speaking generally or providing advice for future action, rather than reporting on your former forays into the fast-paced world of shoe sizing.

> > P.S.: The intended use is a technical publication, so please no colloquial terms and phrases.

Well, 'go (up|down)' is *somewhat* colloquial but it's not so informal as '**upsize**', '**+1ed**', &c. It's basic and perfectly clear Germanic vocab that more of your readers will understand than latinate verbiage like 'increment', 'augment', or—Heaven forfend—'decrement' or 'wax greater employing an incremence of one'. As long as you're not *trying* to stay latinate just to sound smarter, it should be fine.

Answer (score -5):

Shoe size may be graded in length- perhaps increased by one cm/m or any unit.

Or depending on the situation; the shoe  has increased by one than the original size/ by one more than the original size.