# Is there a non-technical word in English that means "to add one"?

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics

As a computer scientist, I ran into trouble recently with a piece of my game writing for a general audience, which had a few phrases like this:

> For magic, each boost increments quantity.

The intention here was for "increment" to mean "adds one to", which is what it means in the technical field of computing. But I had some readers be confused by that, and I realize now that the English dictionary definition of "increment" doesn't say the same thing. E.g., the [definition at dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/increment).

Example of the feedback I received (from a fellow programmer):

> I'm not sure exactly how much increments quantity means, unless Dan is
> nerdily assuming people will just read that as quantity++

("quantity++" is the syntax used in a C-like language to add one to an integer quantity, called the [increment operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators); e.g., as in C, C#, Java, JavaScript, Go, etc... and something of an inside joke in the name of the language C++.)

Note that this question is distinguished from [this related one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/453689/synonym-for-increase-by-one-for-use-in-technical-publication), which asks for usage in a technical publication, and whose answer is "increment", which in my case readers have found to be unclear.

Am I overlooking any other single word in standard English which specifically means "to add one"?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142244/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-r-collins-is-there-a-non-technical-word-in-eng).

Comment: I'm by far not a native speaker of English, but I'm a programmer, and I would say that even in programming context "increment" does not always mean "increment by one".

Comment: Even if the sentence was "For magic, each boost adds 1 to the quantity.", it would still be extremely unclear. What quantity are we adding 1 to? It's unclear whether "for magic" applies to "boost" or to "the quantity" or to something else.  It might mean "Each magic boost increases the quantity by 1" or it might mean "Each boost increases the quantity of magic by 1" or it might mean "Each magic boost increases the quantity of magic by 1" or it might mean something else.

Comment: I don't think "increment" is a technical word...

Comment: @Petr Indeed, and I feel that 'increment', when used alone to mean 'increment by one', it is merely a contraction of the latter.

Comment: I don't think the issue is that they don't know "increment," but more likely that the units of 'magic' are unclear.  And I'm not sure it make sense to "increment quantity."  You sort of need to increment the quantity of something.  Is this the quantity of magic as in the now have more kinds of magic?  Or does magic have some unit and they now have one more of that unit?  If the later, then "Each boost increments your magic points by one," would be much more clear (where 'points' are the unit of magic in this example).

Comment: In a gaming context, I'd expect to see something like "each boost gives +1 MP" or similar...

Comment: There's no word, but maybe you could use "+1"?

Comment: It may still be too technical, but I think the second definition of **linear**: *progressing from one stage to another in a single series of steps; sequential.*

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Summarising the other answers and comments, the answer to OP's question is "No"; there is no word meaning "increase by 1" in general English.

In computer programming the verb "increment" often has that meaning, but in general it means "increase by steps". See  https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-verb-for/increment.html. The steps are often equal to 1, especially for counters. However the steps need not even be the same size, as in wordhippo's example

> “The voltage is then incremented and the process continues until a determination is made as to the objects operability.”

OP's example could be rephrased more clearly as

> For magic, each boost adds 1 to the quantity.

Comment: **This.** I don’t understand why some people insist on coming up with ever more tenuous pseudo-synonyms instead of admitting there isn’t actually a word meeting the criteria listed. (This is hardly the only question on ELU where I see this.) Though even if there isn’t a single word, for completeness it would be nice to at least mention how the idea would be expressed in everyday English.

Comment: @user3840170 Human nature. But I agree that it compromises the integrity of the site.

Comment: @user3840170 While I agree that scrolling down through single-word-request answers usually leads to increments in facepalming, do you think it's a bit bold or at least premature (in general) to claim to have proved a negative with such authority?

Comment: Selecting this as the answer. If someone does find a word that fits the bill at a later date, happy to switch at that time.

Comment: @user3840170 I see an alarming number of posts on English Language Stack coming up with unbelievably tenuous suggestions for something that doesn't have a specific word in English.

Answer (score 20):

You are using "increment" correctly here in the programming sense; I'm not sure if that meaning is known to general audiences.

The reason your audience is confused may be partly related to the missing definite article: "For magic, each boost increments **the** quantity."

One way to avoid the word "increment" would be to rephrase the sentence entirely; this will depend on context, but you might use something like: "Each boost gives you one more point of magic."

Comment: "One more point of magic" makes the most sense in a game setting, and doesn't sound as technical as "adding 1 to the quantity". So one more point of reputation to your answer :)

Comment: For a non-technical audience, I'd further edit this to either "each boost slightly increases the quantity" (or perhaps "bumps"). If the "by 1" is vital, then it has to be said. "each boost increases the quantity by 1".

Comment: increment does not mean "increase by one" in the "programming sense". It means exactly the same as it does everywhere else; increase by some amount.

Answer (score 8):

I'd expect to see "increments by one" if there was any doubt about the size of change.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Aside from the above comments, please don't "sign" answers; Stack Exchange sites are **not discussion forums**.

Answer (score 6):

It was not easy do find your definition on the web, but it is there:

> To add a number to another number. ***Incrementing a counter means adding 1 to its current value***. ([pcmag](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/increment))

One dictionary that does mention it as a verb in Computing is [OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=increment%20meaning&ei=fiPMY_y5G4-TgQazooWoDA&oq=increment%20&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQARgAMgwIABCxAxBDEEYQ-QEyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQ6BQgAEJECOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToRCC4QgAQQsQMQxwEQ0QMQ1AI6FAguEIAEELEDEIMBEMcBENEDENQCOggIABCABBCxAzoECAAQQzoKCAAQsQMQgwEQQzoKCAAQkQIQRhD5AToNCAAQsQMQkQIQRhD5AToICAAQsQMQkQI6BwgAELEDEEM6CwguEIAEEMcBEK8BSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUABY2Rpg5SloAHABeACAAWCIAZYGkgECMTCYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp), but the value of the increase is not specified:

> COMPUTING
> cause a *discrete* increase in (a numerical quantity).

So I am not surprised that the users who are not computing initiates are confused by this. I don't think there is another word. Might be worth considering adding a definition, or simply use *increase by 1*.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators) explains that

> ***Increment*** and ***decrement*** operators are *unary operators that **add or subtract one***, to or from their operand, respectively.
> They are commonly implemented in imperative programming languages.

Comment: Maybe it's worth adding that *decrement* means to decrease the value by one, in the same context.

Comment: I should note that this meaning is well-known among programmers; I'm surprised to learn that non-programmers *don't* use the word this way. For one example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment

Comment: The answer is based on false premise. We may agree that in the context of a **counter**, increments are reasonably understood to be unity. But the question does not refer explicitly to a counter so the increments remain undefined. Boosts in games might be understood, for example, as 1, 10, 25, 100 and so forth. Indeed, any number that is chosen for the game reward structure.

Comment: @Anton In programming (in my experience) the term is used unambiguously to mean "add one" in all cases, not just with counters. (You could say "increment it by 5," but "increment x" on its own would always be interpreted as "add one to x.") PCMag and Oxford have it wrong, but the MDN page I linked uses it correctly.

Comment: @alphabet In the overwhelmingly most widespread uses in programming, the word (/operator) is applied to an integer whose natural discrete step is 1. For me, the original sentence only makes sense in its intended meaning if it can be assumed from context that magic quantity is a variable (it is bad practice outside technical manuals; but I could accept it), that the quantity is an integer (which I cannot accept without more direct context), and that its incremental step is one (which I can accept had it been specified as an integer).

Comment: @xngtng The MDN article I cited is referring to floating point JavaScript numbers.  I stand by my claim that "increment" is used exclusively *in programming* to mean "to add one to something."

Comment: (Unless you specifically state "increment X *by 5,*" of course.)

Comment: @alphabet By one?  Not quite I think.  By one "unit," sure.  Often the unit is assumed from the context, but 'incrementing the RNG' certainly doesn't mean to add one... it means to advance it one 'step' which gives us a (hopefully unrelated per se) pseudo-random number.  Another case may be working with some vector classes, which may have a non-one 'stride', etc...  JavaScript isn't exactly great about types...  And in C++ increment and decrement may often be defined and/or overridden appropriately to e.g. move to the next vector element, even if that isn't one byte.

Comment: @ttbek Yes, by one. C++'s "++" operator can be overridden to do things other than incrementing, just like the "+" operator can be overridden to do things other than addition. In C/C++, incrementing a float adds 1, not epsilon. Incrementing a pointer adds 1, not to the (undefined, possibly nonexistent) integer representation, but to the logical *index* within the larger structure.

Comment: @alphabet The index MUST have some units for you to "add 1" to it, it isn't really meaningful to say that you're adding 1 unless we know what the 1 thing being added is.  These needn't even be indexed in quite that sense, e.g. in the case of linked lists.  What if I say: "Let's time some code.  Let t0 be the start time, after each function call increment t0."  This doesn't mean do t0++, and there's no index. The "unit" to increment by is the time for each respective call.  Yes, of one call, but "add 1" doesn't really capture that meaning.

Comment: @alphabet "In C/C++, incrementing a float adds 1, not epsilon."  I have some bad news for you there, have you read IEEE754?  Try "incrementing" 5e50, or try starting with x = 1.0/3.0, print it out with enough precision, then x++;, then print it again.  I'm not emphasizing that 1/3 can't be exactly represented, but that it does not add exactly one to get the result:
0.3333333333333333148296...
1.3333333333333332593184...
That is one double precision floating point number is NOT one, we do care what this "one" is... (well it is one, but the actual increment is not by that value).

Answer (score 6):

The single-word term **bump** is sometimes used, see [Dictionary of Computing](http://foldoc.org/bump)

> **bump**
> Increment. E.g. C's `++` operator. It is used especially of counter variables, pointers and index dummies in `for`, `while`, and `do-while` loops.

A more general usage is shown in [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bump)

> **bump** *verb* (INCREASE)
> to increase something

So the article or manual you are writing might say

> For magic, each boost bumps the quantity.

Comment: This has the same problem presented in the question - even if people understand "bump" to mean increment, one of the examples givin in the dictionary link is "Minimum wage in the state was bumped 55 cents an hour to $5.85. ", the amount of increment need not be by a single unit.

Comment: You could say "bump it up by one."

Answer (score 5):

The answer is clearly "No." However, I'm rather surprised these expert software programmers don't seem to be aware of *why* "increment" normally means one in computers but is far more varied in the real world.

In the real world, "increment" is the *smallest unit of measure* on a measuring device (whether a ruler, pressure meter, etc). I'm looking at a ruler with 1/64 inch increments right now.

That's a very familiar term to many many people.

Applied to the action of incrementing, several of the definitions given above are quite misleading.

To increment is to *increase by the smallest unit of measure* in the system.

Thus, it's almost meaningless without knowing the context.

To beat this to death:

- increment is applied to a particular context, typically some kind of counter or control variable
- the context determines the size of the increment (or "bump" as some would have it)
- by default traditionally the size is one for computer loops, yet it clearly can be any value at all.

With that in mind it ought to be obvious why "add one" isn't a particularly useful concept, and thus not likely to ever become its own word. *Context is everything.*

(Off Topic: Those with very long term memories will know the meaning and value of a similar computer term... but one that has long been out of favor: JFFO on the PDP10. One of my favorite operations! This single instruction could discover increments ;) )

Comment: In the days of line number BASIC, we would often *increment* line numbers by 10 to leave space for other lines to be added in.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single word that means "to add one", and even if there was one it may not be a good choice of word anyways. That's because you're not just writing text, you're writing rules.

Rules are a kind of technical document, in that they have to explain a topic clearly and precisely, and in general leave no room for interpretation where none is desired.

---

It's true that in the context of computing, a developer would say "increment" without any further precision to mean "increment by 1". However, that's a colloquial use. "Increment" isn't a technical word, and it has a plain English meaning:

- *To increment* means to increase a value.
- The *increment* is the amount by which you increase it.

You can find that meaning used in accounting and finance, e.g. [salary increment](https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/pay-salary/salary-increment) which you would hope isn't be an increase by 1. Which means, if anything, that using "increment" alone could be understood by the right audience in the right but would be woefully unprecise anywhere else.

---

Now here is for example how the [C# reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators) explains what the *increment operator* is, emphasis added:

> The unary increment operator `++` **increments** its operand **by 1**.

"Increment" is the exact verb to use here. However, it can't be used on its own because, as you found out and as discussed above, that would be incomplete. Considering the increment operator does exactly what you want, you could take inspiration and write:

> For magic, each boost increments [quantity] by 1.

*(Assuming here that "quantity" is a placeholder for the actual quantity in-game, e.g. "the target's magic points", which should be specifically specified, specifically so)*

That's clear, precise, and a player can't argue that "you didn't say by how much I should increment my magic so I chose +∞, show me in the rules where it says I can't".

Answer (score 0):

**Tally** can have this meaning: you tally or tally up something (like goals, or the number of people in the stands) by marking the new count, one at a time.  See also [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tally) and [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tally).

**Count up** also works, although it’s two words, not one.

Answer (score -3):

The standard English word meaning "increase by one" is "increment," and it's not just a technical term.  If your audience doesn't know that word, that's their problem, not yours.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).